# Model creation on ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, png

I need to create a model. I have a group of regions (A, B, C)
each one of those has multiple rasters and some other shapefiles. For every region is needed to calculate the area of every region content in the attribute table of each shape, then to export every table to a .xls file. Also, I have to display certain symbology, add the legend and export it as a png image.
So, I have region "A, B, C"; each of those has raster "1, 2, 3" and shapefiles   "I, II, III".In the end, there has to be a .png image with its own legend and a .xls table of every 1,2,3, and I, II, III.

I started with shapefiles because i found it easier, but i dont know how to get the .png files.

Ignore the names within the figures.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool within ModelBuilder that allows you to export the layout. The only way you can do that in an automated way is to call the the arcpy function [ExportToPNG](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm). You could create a script to do this, see the sample code on the help page, and either call that within a [Calculate Value tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) or [wire the script up and expose it as a tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm) in the geo-processing framework.